# How do I make a Login System in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am new to this site so I am sorry if there are any inaccuracies in this question. I am trying to create a login system using a local database. Previously I did some research on how to make a login system but still have no luck. I am using something like `intent.putExtras()` (sorry, not sure what the correct word for that is) to store user's details such as username, date of birth etc, so the following activity can receive the data from the previous activity. However, I just figured out that `SharedPreferences` is used by many people to implement a login system and I am planning on using it as I have an impression that it is more reliable (correct me if I am wrong). However, I have been implementing a login system using `intent.putExtras()` and never seen anyone implementing a login system that way. To make sure my current way of implementation is **reliable**, my question is, can I use `intent.putExtras()` instead of using `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intent.putExtras(//something)` only stores data in `Bundle` temporarily. You need to store the user info (or if user has logged in) somewhere, to be accessed next time you open the application.

`intent.putExtras()` are intended to be used, for example, when you want to pass data from one Activity to another.

Locally, sqlite and shared preferences are your only options.

> My question is, can I use "intent.putExtras(//something)" instead of using SharedPreferences?

With what you want to achieve, no you can't.

---

After you edited your question:

If you only want to pass data then you can do so with `intent.putExtras()`, if you want to store data locally, then you will have to use sqlite or shared preferences.

Comment: I am using sqlite and intent.putExtras()

Comment: Like I said `If you only want to pass data then you can do so with intent.putExtras()`

Comment: For instance, in my login system, I pass user's inputs from there to another activity and the data are stored in a database.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is only to store data, since it's already stored in SQLite you don't have to use `SharedPreferences` again, just use `intent.putExtras(//something)`